# $g_n(x)=\frac{\frac{x}{n\:}}{1+\frac{x^2}{n^2}\:}$ proving uniform convergence

Tags: calculus, analysis

$$g_n(x)=\frac{\frac{x}{n\:}}{1+\frac{x^2}{n^2}\:}$$

I have to show that it converges uniformly in $[0,\infty)$, I already got that it converges pointwise to $\frac{1}{2}$ but I am just stuck on uniformly proving it.

I have tried using Weierstrass M-Test and Abel's Uniform Convergence Test, but I always reach something not logical.

Comment: You should revise your calculations regarding pointwise convergence. Note that for example, $g_n(0) = 0 \ (\forall n)$ so we do not have pointwise convergence to $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: $g_n(\infty)=0$, so something is fishy here

Comment: To clarify . . . converges as $n\to\infty$ or as $x\to\infty$?

Comment: I used the inequality of $a^2 + b^2 \ge 2ab$ and so it all got canceled neatly, can you pls explain why it is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g_n$ does not converge uniformly. It converges pointwise to 0 and $g_n(n)=\frac 1 2$ so it does not converge uniformly.

Comment: Thank for the answer, but now I have hit a wall in the last part of the question.
we are given another function in the beginning of the question that is:
$h_n(x) = \frac{xn}{1+x^2n^2}$ and it goes like this. define a new function $k_n(x) = g_n(x) * h_n(x)$, does it uniformly converge?
I tried multiple algebraical ways to solve and simplify it but it just wont work.

Comment: @David what does * stand for? (Convolution or just the product?).

Comment: the product of both functions, probably should have left out the *

Comment: @David You can easily see that $|h_n(x)| \leq \frac 1 {n^{2}}$ so $h_n \to 0$ uniformly.

Comment: Ye but my question was over the function $k_n(x)$ which I defined as the product of both, $g_n(x)$ doesn't converge uniformly and I just cant seem to get a final say as to whether $k_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent.

Comment: @David Sorry, there was a typo in the last comment. I meant $|k_n(x)| \leq \frac 1 {n^{2}}$. So $k_n \to 0$ uniformly.